# Postgres card order database schema?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have a `user` table and a `card` table, like this:

```
user: user_id

card: card_id user_id card_text card_order
```

As of right now, a user can have up to five cards. Users should also be able to re-arrange their cards on the frontend. So let's say a user had four cards, with the text for each one being "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Donut", respectively.

The users should be able to re-arrange them and this change should be persisted into the database. So for example, an example schema where the order was `Apple`, `Carrot`, `Donut`, and `Banana` would look like this:

```
card_id   user_id   card_text   card_order
------------------------------------------
  23         1        Apple         1
  53         1        Banana        4
  43         1        Carrot        2
  58         1        Donut         3
```

Is there a better way to do this? My issue is with updating them.

Let's say the user drags the `Banana` card to the #2 slot. Then `Apple` would stay `1`, `Banana` would become `2`, `Carrot` would become `3`, and `Donut` would become `4`. I'm not exactly sure what sort of SQL code I would have to execute to perform that sort of logic. Maybe something like..

```
UPDATE card SET card_order = card_order + 1 WHERE user_id = $1 AND card_order >= $2;
UPDATE card SET card_order = $2 WHERE user_id $1 AND card_id = $2;
```

Something like that? Not sure, but I feel like there is a better way?

An alternative is to have something like a `card_order` column in the `user` table which contains the ordering like: `[ 23, 43, 58, 53 ]`, which may be easier to re-arrange, but then I have to do a `JOIN` with the `user` table every time I want to get the cards in the correct order. In addition, I'm not sure how well foreign keys would work in that situation? I fear the array could accidentally get corrupted with old card ids if the referential integrity was not checked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `double precision` or `numeric` for `card_order`. Then you can easily move a card somewhere else without the need to update all other cards: just set `card_order` to the arithmetic mean of the `card_order`s of the cards between which the card should move.

Comment: Couldn't this eventually have precision issues leading to false orders as the means converge?

Comment: If you have that many rearrangements, use `numeric`. That has almost unlimited precision.